# how to disable my services in my android application?

Tags: android

i am beginner in android development and i develop application with activties and services . now i want to add new option which that disable application. how to stop this services

Comment: **now i want to add new option which that disable application** pls be more specific

Answer (score 1):

To start the service:

```
startService(new Intent(ThisActivity.this, YourService.class));
```

To stop the service:

```
stopService(new Intent(ThisActivity.this, YourService.class));
```

They can be called from anywhere within your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [Service Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to stop the service in normal execution. If needed the OS will do that for you.

If you Service has started any background threads then you should stop those of course. But that is done the normal Java way.

You should read [Multitasking the Android Way](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010_04_01_archive.html).